# Google wont display the url under search results

Tags: url, google-search

As things used to be, each google search result would show in the first line the page title, underneath in green text the part of the url of the page (at least the domain), next to that links for cached version and translation, underneath some matched text etc.
The problem is that for a week or so now the green text with the url us usually just '...'

Is that a new policy? is there a way to fix it(like a greasemonkey script)?

Comment: Questions on webservices are off topic as per FAQ. If you really want a software solution to this please make the question more specific. Else it might be better to have it migrated to webapps.SE (if they want it).

Comment: FWIW, I don't see this. Can you include a screenshot maybe? Does it happen in all browsers, and when you're logged into Google or not? Any search settings you changed?

Comment: This firefox plugin might be what you aim for? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix/

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently was that in greek the 'cached' link and the link to translate took up too much space leaving none for the URL. I switched to english and now all is good!